# SortedMap manipulation using foldleft

Tags: scala, dictionary, foldleft

I have a code that converts the following datatypes:

from: SortedMap[Long, SortedMap[String, Double]]
to: SortedMap[String, Array[Double]]

Can anyone please explain how this code does the above manipulation?

```
val convertedDataWindow = dataWindow.values.foldLeft(SortedMap.empty[String, Array[Double]]) {
  case (res0, map) =>
    (res0 /: map) {
      case (res1, (key, value)) =>
        res1.updated(key, res1.getOrElse(key, Array.empty) :+ value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the inner function on its own first:

```
def something(res0: SortedMap[String, Array[Double]],
  map: SortedMap[String, Double]) = (res0 /: map) {
  case (res1, (key, value)) =>
    res1.updated(key, res1.getOrElse(key, Array.empty) :+ value)
}
```

`/:` is another name for `foldLeft`, this is the same as

```
map.foldLeft(res0) { ...}
```

You know how `foldLeft` works in general? It runs through the collection, using the given function to "merge" each value into the initial value in turn. So this starts with `res0`, and for every `(key, value)` in `map`, we merge it into our working result using `.updated`: we add a new entry to the map, with key `key` and value `res1.getOrElse(key, Array.empty) :+ value`. That is, if there's already an entry for this key, we add `value` onto the end of it; otherwise, we make a new `Array` containing just `value`.

So putting all that together, what this function is doing is merging `map` into `res0`, by making new entries for any new keys, or putting the values onto the `Array` for any existing keys.

Now, the full function is doing another `foldLeft`; we could write it as:

```
dataWindow.values.foldLeft(SortedMap.empty)(something)
```

So what this is doing is starting from an empty map, and then for each of `dataWindow.values` in turn, merging that into our working map.

(Of course when I talk about "merging", in reality everything is immutable and we're creating a new "working" map every time we go through the loop. But sometimes it's clearer to imagine a single, mutable "working" map `res`)